# Scrollview content shows but not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a `ViewController` with a `ScrollView` containing bunch of content from `IB` but the scrollview isn't working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
/*
 *  configure a bunch of label, text ,images and views from IB
*/

    UIScrollView* scrollView = (UIScrollView*)self.view;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 2000);
}
```

I can see my content up until the bottom but can't scroll.  If it means anything, this `ViewController` in one of the tabs in a `TabBar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For scroll view to scroll its Frame size must be smaller then its Content Size
2. You have added the scrollView FROM code programatically but looks like you are talking about adding it through Xcode's Storyboard or in nib file
3. IF you are adding it thought code you need to add following code

[self.view addSubView:scrollView];

Here is one example

```
@interface ImageScrollView ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIPageControl *pageControl;
@end

-(void) baseInit {
    // Scroll View - Full frame width
    _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    _scrollView.frame = self.frame;
    _scrollView.delegate = self;

    // ImageView - Full frame width
    CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height;

    int i = 0;
    int count = [imagesArray count];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagesArray[i]];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * width, 0, width, height)];
        [imageView setImage:image];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        imageView.tag = i+1;
        [_scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }

    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(count * width,  height)];
    [_scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    _scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    _scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

    pageControl.numberOfPages = count;
    pageControl.currentPage = 0;
     CGRect pageFrame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50);
    pageControl.frame = pageFrame;
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self addSubview:_scrollView];
    [_scrollView addSubview:pageControl];
}
```

Dont forget to call baseInit function in your view did load. 
This example work without needing to add any objects in Storyboard or nib files